# Visual Studio 2019 Community (Offline) Installation for Unity failed

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have tried it [Offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) Method for Visual Studio; Everything was fine while downloading and installation (on My another PC) but when integrating in Unity it fails to open with no error. Logo Appears,Sounds beeps and nothing happens then. Kindly brief me what is the problem? Either should i download Visual Studio again (for UNITY) or Installation again what should i do?

I downloaded Visual Studio with full updated , while my other on which i am installing has no Internet and not updated from 2 years. Both Windows 10..

Comment: BTW i am installing VS 2019 due to No IntelliSense in VSCode and MonoDevelop. May be VS2019 solved my problem ...

Comment: i think you need to run vs outside unity first to select how you want it to look etc.. i think unity tries to hide some of these and it hides in the background

Comment: @BugFinder In Background how can i enable it?

Comment: just run visual studio once outside unity, it will ask you its questions and then its done.  It should open fine there on after

Comment: Thanks problem Solved by Updating .NET framwork